# How to use adress returned from call

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

everybody!

I'm trying to make some project using assembly functions, which call from c. In c, I use errno.h. So I want to write errors, related with  syscalls to errno for able to use perror etc. I know that syscall return to rax negative value if failed, so -rax = code of error.

in my errno.h error described as extern int *__error(void).

In my opinion if I detected, that return from syscall less than zero, i need to call ___error and after it I need to write -rax to return from ___error, but I don't know how.

I use macOS and NASM. To be more exact, there is a prototype my write func:

```
        global  _ft_write
        extern  ___error

_ft_write:
            mov rax, 0x2000004
            syscall
            cmp rax, 0
            jl errno
            ret

errno:
            call ___error
            mov rax, [rax]
            neg rax    
            ret

for compile: nasm -fmacho64
```

There is my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int         main(void)
{
    printf("Write return: %d\n", ft_write(15, "wrong file descriptor", 3));
    printf("Error code: %d\n", errno);  return(1);
}
```

output:
Write return: 9
Error code: 0

*P. S. I'm new in assembly, sorry if question is stupid and thanks in advance.*

Comment: `mov <yourTargetRegister>, [rax]`?

Comment: Well obviously you need to store the rax somewhere else so you can write to it. "I did `rax = something(); rax = somethingElse();`. How can I do `*theSecondRax = theFirstRax` when `rax` got overwritten? Answer: use a different variable. You are [this programmer here](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/I-Didn%E2%80%99t-Know-You-Could-Do-That!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__error` returns an pointer to an int in `rax`.
So you have to do two steps:

1. Dereference pointer to get value
2. Return `-rax`.

Dereference:

```
mov rax, [rax] ;Nearly equals to rax= (*rax)
```

Negate rax:

```
neg rax ; rax=-rax
```

Edit, based on your comments:
Just use:

```
mov <someFreeRegister>, qword [rax]
neg <someFreeRegister>
mov qword [rax], <someFreeRegister>
```

Comment: So, I edited my post with your advices and return of my functionalists is expectable, but func didn't change value of ___error

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to change the value, the pointer points too, not a copy of it. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it! And I don'n know how to do it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sure, that it is working, but i can't test it, because i found another mistake... syscall with wrong file descriptor don't change my rax with negative value... I was sure that it have to do this